# will magento community edition supports "Activation key" for mobile apps

Tags: android, magento

we are trying to generate a android app through magento site.

it's asking for "Activation Key ".

http://prntscr.com/6oyt3m

I want to know what is the "Activation key"? how it's going to be usefull....

if i click on that " Activation Key", it's redirecting to "enterprise edition"

please help me to get "Activation key" in magento community edition

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a quick search on google I came up with a more recent result and according to [this](http://sherodesigns.com/how-to-make-your-magento-store-mbile-friendly-mobile-app-or-responsive-design/) it's a paid feature.

in this article it says the following about pricing

> Magento Mobile is priced per device family (iPad, iPhone, and
>   Android). As of February 2014, each of them costs (rounding up) $699
>   for setup plus any other fees that might apply. If you want support
>   for all three, the cost for the first year, is almost $2097.

I tried searching for this on the magento site but I came up empty.

Comment: fine, is we have to pay only for "activation key" or for "enterprise edition" if only for "activation key", how much?

Comment: thanks , but the article link is not opening..... can you please post article link again....

Comment: i am getting this error, when i tried to acces the article..... : You don't have permission to access /how-to-make-your-magento-store-mbile-friendly-mobile-app-or-responsive-design/ on this server.

Comment: not sure why it's giving you that error. try this 
http://sherodesigns.com/category/magento-mobile/

Comment: alright try it like this. if that doesn't work I have no clue what is going wrong for you. http://sherodesigns.com/how-to-make-your-magento-store-mbile-friendly-mobile-app-or-responsive-design/

Comment: now its opening.....  means if we want "activation key", we have to pay..... am i right?

Comment: Part of the Magento "stuff flung at the wall to see if it would stick" that disappeared during the "Mag-E-Bay" website redesign. Not sure if Magento is still selling the access for Community Edition, at the time it was going to cost about 2 grand USD a year. About the time I got ready to start playing mobile, link rot and disappearance set in.